# Find zero in front of any number in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have these number 00012001, 0000012002, 012003, 12004 etc. If one of these number is selected randomly, i would like to find zero in front of number and store in string.

For example,

If 00012001 is selected, '000' is stored in String variable.

If 0000012002 is selected, then '00000' is stored in String. There may or may not have zero in front of number.

Is there a way to find zero in front of these number? Thanks.

Comment: What means _selected_, selected where? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With LINQ it's easy:

```
Dim zeros = selected.ToString().TakeWhile(Function(c) c = "0"c)
Dim zeroString = New String(zeros.ToArray())
```

Another approach that comes to my mind:

```
dim countZeros =  selected.Length - selected.TrimStart("0"c).Length
zeroString = New string("0"c, countZeros)
```

---

Trevor said it was a good candidate for an extension, here is an optimized version:

```
Public Module StringExtensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
    Public Function TrimStartGetTrimmed(str As String, ParamArray charsToTrim As Char()) As String
        If str Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(str))
        End If
        Dim whiteSpaceCheck As Boolean = charsToTrim Is Nothing OrElse charsToTrim.Length = 0

        Dim firstNonTrimCharIndex As Integer = 0
        For Each current As Char In str
            Dim isTrimChar As Boolean = If(whiteSpaceCheck, Char.IsWhiteSpace(current), charsToTrim.Contains(current))
            If Not isTrimChar Then
                Return str.Substring(0, firstNonTrimCharIndex)
            End If
            firstNonTrimCharIndex += 1
        Next
        Return str
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
    Public Function TrimEndGetTrimmed(str As String, ParamArray charsToTrim As Char()) As String
        If str Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(str))
        End If
        Dim whiteSpaceCheck As Boolean = charsToTrim Is Nothing OrElse charsToTrim.Length = 0

        For index = str.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Dim current As Char = str(index)
            Dim isTrimChar As Boolean = If(whiteSpaceCheck, Char.IsWhiteSpace(current), charsToTrim.Contains(current))
            If Not isTrimChar Then
                Return str.Substring(index + 1)
            End If
        Next
        Return str
    End Function
End Module
```

Here the same for C#:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string TrimStartGetTrimmed(this string str, params char[] charsToTrim)
    {
        if (str == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(str));
        bool whiteSpaceCheck = charsToTrim == null || charsToTrim.Length == 0;

        for (var index = 0; index < str.Length; index++)
        {
            char current = str[index];
            bool isTrimChar = whiteSpaceCheck ? char.IsWhiteSpace(current) : charsToTrim.Contains(current);
            if (!isTrimChar)
                return str.Substring(0, index);
        }
        return str;
    }

    public static string TrimEndGetTrimmed(this string str, params char[] charsToTrim)
    {
        if (str == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(str));
        bool whiteSpaceCheck = charsToTrim == null || charsToTrim.Length == 0;

        for (var index = str.Length - 1; index >= 0; index--)
        {
            char current = str[index];
            bool isTrimChar = whiteSpaceCheck ? char.IsWhiteSpace(current) : charsToTrim.Contains(current);
            if (!isTrimChar)
                return str.Substring(index + 1);
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: The 2nd one is a LOT faster

Comment: @Trevor: in 99.9% it doesn't matter because you don't need to do it 10000000 times and it's not critical if the user sees it 1ms sooner or later.

Comment: True enough @TimSchmelter. But still.. worth mentioning. This would  also be a good candidate for a string extension too.

Answer (score 0):

This should work too:

```
Function zerodigits(ByVal str As String)
    Dim re As String = ""
    For Each c As Char In str
        Select Case c
            Case "0"c : re &= c
            Case Else : Return re
        End Select
    Next
    Return re
End Function
```